# What is a good tool that can traverse deep NTFS paths?

Tags: file-server

There are some files on our fileserver that cannot be deleted, because the directory structure is too deep.

I have read: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320081 and at resolution #5 it is suggested to use a tool that can traverse deep paths. I am looking for some names of tools which can do this.

Comment: Actually I have been able to delete the files and directories using the simple rd /s command from a command prompt. But I am still interested in a GUI-tool which can traverse and operate on deep paths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the system can be interrupted, then booting up Ubuntu Desktop will enable file management of deep NTFS paths via a GUI.

Comment: Indeed. A Parted Magic live-cd has proven a very useful tool in my sysadmin toolbox.